# Could not load file or assembly 'XXX' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure

I have two projects (Crestfine and CrestfineWebapp) that i have deployed on Azure Web app service. However the Web app fails to run citing an error

```
   Could not load file or assembly 'crestfine' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Crestfine here being web API which runs fine. CrestfineWebapp throws this error

Assembly Load Trace:

```
   WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]
```

Stack Trace:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'crestfine' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +95
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError) +63
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type requiredContextType, String contextTypeName, String initializerTypeName, Boolean isDisabled, Func`1 initializerArgs, Func`3 exceptionMessage) +46

[InvalidOperationException: Failed to set database initializer of type 'System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[crestfine.DAL.CrestfineContext, crestfine], [crestfine.Migrations.Configuration, crestfine]], EntityFramework, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' for DbContext type 'crestfine.DAL.CrestfineContext, crestfine' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.]
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type requiredContextType, String contextTypeName, String initializerTypeName, Boolean isDisabled, Func`1 initializerArgs, Func`3 exceptionMessage) +326
 System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass6.<TryGetInitializerFromEntityFrameworkSection>b__1(ContextElement e) +276
 System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +223
 System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +115
 System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type contextType) +23
 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type type, String name) +534
 System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +84
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key) +187
 System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +75
 System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +115
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key) +41
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +159
  System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +174
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +269
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +38
  System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +77
  System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetAsyncEnumerator() +21
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ForEachAsync(IDbAsyncEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +69
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ToListAsync(IDbAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +315
```

I've set the Azure Platform architecture to 64bit
[image]

Locally they both run fine with the following settings
[image]

[image]

Comment: You set Azure to 64x, but build for Any CPU. If there are x86 dependencies, I think it will be build for x86 and not x64.

Comment: I tried to publish with 64x specified but the error persists

Comment: Try to set this assembly "Copy local" to "True", as shown here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2013/01/09/how-to-resolve-the-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-issues-on-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: It worked thank you. Write it as an official answer for me to approve it. To Help others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution was sent on my comment section, pretty easy to solve [Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2013/01/09/how-to-resolve-the-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-issues-on-windows-azure-web-sites/)

I went ahead an added the CrestFine (web api) reference to the CrestfineWebApp.In addition I changed the platform target to:

[image]

from

```
AnyCPU
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19139359)

Comment: I appreciate, I've made the necessary changes